# Nativescript Angular Dynamic Grid Layout From Array

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, nativescript, grid-layout

Nativescript newbie here! I have been trying to display items inside an array of objects in a grid format (like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-grid-view) to no avail. I am able to loop through and display the items in a normal listview with the code below:

```
<GridLayout>
    <ListView [items]="itemList" class="small-spacing">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Here's my array structure:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"item1"},{"id":2, "name":"item2"},{"id":3, "name":"item3"},{"id":4, "name":"item4"},...]
```

I would love to be able to dynamically/programmatically generate and populate cells in a grid with data from the sample array above in columns of 2 or 3 (max) as below:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
|             |             |             |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have tried the very few mentions of this scenario I found online, but no joy - please help!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to achieve this for a list of items is to use [RadListView with StaggeredLayout](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts#using-listviewstaggeredlayout). The RadListView is free to use with nativescript-telerik-ui (non-pro version) and can be set to order its items in staggered cells as shown in the link above.

```
<ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout spanCount="3"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>
```

Full demo demonstrating how to use RadListView with staggered layout can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/release/sdk/app/listview/item-layouts/item-layouts-staggered.xml)